# Kohana PHP framework MySQL database connection exception

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, kohana

I have created a website with Kohana PHP framework, version 3.1.3.1. The site is already running well in production. I just returned to it after a year and tried to setup local instance as I need to do some updates on that.

For some reason I keep getting following exception in browser:

```
Database_Exception [ 0 ]:
MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 67 ]
62      catch (ErrorException $e)
63      {
64          // No connection exists
65          $this->_connection = NULL;
66 
67          throw new Database_Exception(':error',
68              array(':error' => mysql_error()),
69              mysql_errno());
70      }
71 
72      // \xFF is a better delimiter, but the PHP driver uses underscore
MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 158 ] » Kohana_Database_MySQL->connect()
MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 347 ] » Kohana_Database_MySQL->query(arguments)
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 1551 ] » Kohana_Database_MySQL->list_columns(arguments)
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 439 ] » Kohana_ORM->list_columns(arguments)
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 386 ] » Kohana_ORM->reload_columns()
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 300 ] » Kohana_ORM->_initialize()
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_ORM->__construct(arguments)
APPPATH/classes/controller/index.php [ 20 ] » Kohana_ORM::factory(arguments)
{PHP internal call} » Controller_Index->action_index()
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php [ 132 ] » ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 1129 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute(arguments)
DOCROOT/index.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

There is no useful debug information attached. The connection to the database itself seems to work, as I do get specific exception while intentionally providing invalid credentials:

```
Database_Exception [ 1045 ]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

this is the extract from "database.php"

```php
'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for MySQL:
             *
             * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
             * string   database     database name
             * string   username     database username
             * string   password     database password
             * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
             *
             * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
             */
            'hostname'   => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'   => 'databasename',
            'username'   => 'root',
            'password'   => '',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
```

I found out that when I change 'database' key for some invalid string the exception 
stays the same. Is it possible the Kohana can connect to MySQL server but fails to access any database?

In order to test it, I tried to execute simple script using "mysqli", inside the Kohana app and var_dump some basic query results. It could connect to the database and listed all the tables though, so it seems there is something funny in the way kohana's ORM module is trying to communicate with database.

I used to get this working under Windows before (year ago..) and I cannot figure out what's wrong now, apart from the fact I switched to linux (using Ubuntu 14.04 now). I am using XAMP for linux (xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run) to run apache, php and mysql.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: So it is still working in production? What OS is on the productive system? have you checked file permissions on your linux system?

Comment: Yes it is working in production. Not entirely sure what OS is being run under, but it seems not to matter as I have tried to set up the Web App locally under Windows too now and got the same issue :-(

Comment: You could try debugging the database connection right in the [Kohana Driver](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Database_MySQL#connect), maybe you'll find some error with that.

Comment: Of course, your straightforward advice did help, I feel quite ashamed now! After removing the exception handler block I could see what was actually wrong - Kohana framework in my version uses still "mysql" driver instead of "mysqli". Problem is that since PHP 5.5.0 "mysql" is no longer supported.That is why this has mysteriously stopped working - I simply used latest PHP now incompatible with the framework. This should be hopefully resolved in future 3.4 version of Kohana http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5455/ko3-mysqli-driver/p1..

Answer (score 0):

If your `root` account don't have password, right syntax is

```
        'password'   => FALSE,
```